# The digits of a number in ascending order. (comparing)

Tags: python

```
cc = input('Input the number: ')
b = str(cc)
c = []
for digit in b:
    c.append (int(digit))
    csort = c.sort(key=int)
    c == csort #??
```

I need to say `True` or `False` if the number is in ascending order or not.

My code do not print `True` or `False`, why?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: You're not printing anything.

Comment: How I could do that? (I need to apply boolean operators)

Comment: if c == csort: print 'True' else: 'False Do not solve it.

Comment: `print c == csort` ?

Comment: remember `list.sort` modifies the original list and returns `None`, so in your code `csort` will always = `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `key=int` in `c.sort(key=int)` as `c` is already a list of `int`s due to you creating it via `c.append(int(digit))`.

However the key issue is that `c.sort()` is in-place and as such returns `None`, instead use `sorted` which returns a sorted `list`:

```
csort = sorted(c)
```

And then you can print the boolean result of the comparsion via:

```
print c == csort
```